# Image processing: rotation

Tags: java, performance, image

I've made two functions for image processing:

1. First one is for rotating an image
2. [Second one](/q/146609/122631) is to set all pixels of one color to another color

**Rotate Image:**

```
private static void roateImage(BufferedImage pic1) throws IOException {
    int width = pic1.getWidth(null);
    int height = pic1.getHeight(null);

    double angle = Math.toRadians(90);
    double sin = Math.sin(angle);
    double cos = Math.cos(angle);
    double x0 = 0.5 * (width - 1);     // point to rotate about
    double y0 = 0.5 * (height - 1);     // center of image

    WritableRaster inRaster = pic1.getRaster();
    BufferedImage pic2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster outRaster = pic2.getRaster();
    int[] pixel = new int[3];

    // rotation
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            double a = x - x0;
            double b = y - y0;
            int xx = (int) (+a * cos - b * sin + x0);
            int yy = (int) (+a * sin + b * cos + y0);

            if (xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height) {
                outRaster.setPixel(x, y, inRaster.getPixel(xx, yy, pixel));
            }
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(pic2, "bmp", new File("Images/Output2.bmp"));
}
```

Please help me to optimize this code.

Comment: You could just leave this open and edit out one of the 2 and just open one more post. By the way looks like there's an error in the spelling of your rotation method, it's spelled "roateImage" instead of rotateImage

Comment: For the rotation, it looks like you are cutting off the corners.  Is that a desirable effect?

Comment: Ok well... I've edit this question and now I have 2 posts, one just with rotation and one just with changing color of pixels. And no @JDub I don't have any kind of effects, or I didn't notice this.

Comment: Do you really want to rotate at arbitrary angles? Most image rotate functions (the basic ones anyway) will work for 90, 180 and 270 degrees only. Any other values really should be done with supersampling or they will look awful from aliasing effects and if you're not careful will contain many holes in the result. I would recommend you stick to just those angles. Now how will width and height be affected if we rotate 90 degrees? These aren't even optimization issues, these are what to watch out for to get it to work in the first place.

Comment: No, I want to rotate just with 90 degree or any kind of multiple of this, like 180 and 270. I will never need to rotate this images with any kind of other angle, just multiples of 90

Comment: @J.D. then you should avoid using sin and cos they are slooooooow. Just swap rows with columns or flip them/reverse them as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Math is fun; why waste it on the computer?

> ```
>     double angle = Math.toRadians(90);
>     double sin = Math.sin(angle);
>     double cos = Math.cos(angle);
> ```

This is the same as

```
    int sin = 1;
    int cos = 0;
```

So

> ```
>             int xx = (int) (+a * cos - b * sin + x0);
>             int yy = (int) (+a * sin + b * cos + y0);
> ```

simplifies to

```
            int xx = (int) (- b + x0);
            int yy = (int) (+a + y0);
```

which simplifies to

```
            int xx = (int) (y0 + x0) - y;
            int yy = x + (int) (y0 - x0);
```

And you don't need `a` or `b` at all.  But you could precalculate

```
    int sum = (int) (y0 + x0);
    int difference = (int) (y0 - x0);
```

right after you calculate `y0` and `x0` (i.e. before the loop).  Then in the loop, you just need

```
            int xx = sum - y;
            int yy = difference + x;
```

Then you could rewrite

> ```
>             if (xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height) {
>                 outRaster.setPixel(x, y, inRaster.getPixel(xx, yy, pixel));
>             }
> ```

as

```
            if (sum >= y && sum - width < y && x >= -difference && x < height - difference) {
                outRaster.setPixel(x, y, inRaster.getPixel(xx, yy, pixel));
            }
```

But then we can change

> ```
>     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
>         for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
> ```

to

```
    int right = Math.min(width, height - difference);
    int bottom = Math.min(height, sum + 1)
    for (int x = Math.max(0, -difference); x < right; x++) {
        for (int y = Math.max(0, sum - width + 1); y < bottom; y++) {
```

Now we don't have to check if `xx` and `yy` fit in the bounds.  We only iterate over the pixels where they do.  So we can drop the `if` and just say

```
            outRaster.setPixel(x, y, inRaster.getPixel(xx, yy, pixel));
```

#### TL;DR

```
private static void rotateImage(BufferedImage pic1) throws IOException {
    int width = pic1.getWidth(null);
    int height = pic1.getHeight(null);

    // point to rotate about center of image
    double x0 = 0.5 * (width - 1);
    double y0 = 0.5 * (height - 1);

    int sum = (int) (y0 + x0);
    int difference = (int) (y0 - x0);

    WritableRaster inRaster = pic1.getRaster();
    BufferedImage pic2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster outRaster = pic2.getRaster();
    int[] pixel = new int[3];

    // rotation
    int right = Math.min(width, height - difference);
    int bottom = Math.min(height, sum + 1)
    for (int x = Math.max(0, -difference); x < right; x++) {
        for (int y = Math.max(0, sum - width + 1); y < bottom; y++) {
            int xx = sum - y;
            int yy = difference + x;

            outRaster.setPixel(x, y, inRaster.getPixel(xx, yy, pixel));
        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(pic2, "bmp", new File("Images/Output2.bmp"));
}
```

I also changed the spelling to `rotateImage`.

Now the only math done inside the loops is incrementing the index variables and simple integer subtraction and addition.

And we only increment over pixels that we're copying.

It's odd to take an image as input and then write a different image to a file.  Why not return the image instead?  Then the caller can save it.

Consider if you can make `inRaster` a `Raster` instead.  I don't think that it needs to be writable, just `outRaster`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really amazing. I've change every thing and now it's truly faster. I really appreciate your help with this, it's really useful :D. Could you help me to optimize and this [function](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146609/color-substitution-in-a-bufferedimage/146610?noredirect=1#comment275494_146610)? I've post it here yesterday and I reallly need to optimize and that function. Thanks again for this one :).

Comment: Math is unbeatable.

Comment: Yes, I've try it and yes it's better. Now the single problem I have with performance it's about get/setRGB from this function because they are to slow....  Do you know what can I try to use there faster? I've try with get/setPixels but from some reason it's not working. Cand you help me with this please?